# Fastest way to create a filesystem image with cloop/create_compressed_fs

Tags: disk-image

Cloop is a linux software package to mount compressed block device images. `create_compressed_fs` is the accompanying tool to create a compressed image of a filesystem (or any kind of file or block device). What is the fastest way to create a filesystem image with it? Assume the source is a partition on one harddisk and the destination is a file on a different disk. Also assume that the source harddisk is the limiting factor in throughput speed.

Answer (score 0):

This answer documents what I learned while attempting to optimize the transfer with `create_compressed_fs`.

`create_compressed_fs` is available in the repository in the `cloop-util` package in Ubuntu 20.04, but the cloop kernel driver is not. To build it, use the source from https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloop, which works for current kernels. The upstream source is out of date. Cloop has been added to Ubuntu 20.10.

`create_compressed_fs` has a number of options, including ones that try to store the entire disk image in memory, so don't use that. Additionally, `create_compressed_fs` as a tendency to stop reading for a few seconds every ten or so seconds, probably to do some internal synchronization or whatever. When it is not reading, the source disk is sitting idle for a few seconds.

If your source is a partition, you might want to make sure the unused data is zeroed to improve compression. Use `fstrim` (if the device supports TRIM) or `zerofree` (if the device does not support TRIM but is an ext2/3/4 filesystem) for that.

First, find the size of the source partition with

```
sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/my-partition
```

If the source is a regular file use `command ls -l my-imagefile`, the size is then the number after the owner and group.

To ensure that the source drive keeps reading at full speed, we want to add a large buffer before `create_compressed_fs`. The `pv` tool can do that, and will also show the throughput and buffer level in real time. As `create_compressed_fs` also generates its own output, we want to run `pv` and `create_compressed_fs` in different terminals so their outputs don't get messed up. Create a fifo to have both processes talk to each other:

```
mkfifo fifo
```

In one terminal, run

```
create_compressed_fs -B <blocksize> -s <input_size> fifo <output_filename>.cloop
```

I like to use `16K` for blocksize, but that is up to you.

At the same time in another terminal, run

```
sudo mbuffer -i <path_to_source_device_or_file> -m 1G >fifo
```

`mbuffer` now uses a 1 GB buffer to keep the source drive busy if `create_compressed_fs` pauses. The buffer should be sized such that it doesn't completely fill up in the pauses, but you should make sure that you have enough memory for the buffer. If you find that the buffer is full all the time and `create_compressed_fs` does not manage to empty it, your source device is not the bottleneck.

I also tried using `pv` to do the buffering, but it doesn't work very well. If it reads from the source block device directly it doesn't get the source drive to produce data at full speed, and it also manages to block when `create_compressed_fs` pauses, even though it should continue reading then. That appears to be a bug.

Once the image is done, don't forget to remove the fifo:

```
rm fifo
```